# Is there a way to call the subview of a view controller's self.view in a function outside of viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Essentially what I'm trying to do here is have a function which sets the alpha of a subview of self.view to 1 (it is hidden by default) which gets called upon pressing a button. i've run into this problem a few times because i declare subviews in viewDidLoad and i don't know of a way to interact with those in a different function (i've tried self.view.subviews[n] but xcode is not happy with that). the only other way i can think of to make this happen is to set self.view equal to the view i want, or maybe even create the view within the function i'm hoping to call with the button (the issue i see with that is potentially the view will not overlay the button, which i want to happen).

here's what i have so far:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *firstBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIView *blackOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    blackOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    firstBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIButton *fakeNotifButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fakeNotifButton addTarget:blackOverlay action:@selector(setupFakeNotifScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //i haven't finished the button yet, that i don't need any help with
}

-(IBAction)setupFakeNotifScreen:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{view = 1.0;} //here is where i want to call blackOverlay
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}

@end
```

edit: i figured it out... didn't even need the blackOverlay view. here's the solution for any future google people... there are probably more efficient ways to do this so i would appreciate anybody who's better than me weighing in:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    

    UIButton *fakeNotifButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fakeNotifButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setupFakeNotifScreen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    fakeNotifButton.frame = CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2) - 80, 300, 160, 40);
    [fakeNotifButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fakeNotifButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor systemGreenColor]];
    fakeNotifButton.layer.cornerCurve = @"continuous";
    fakeNotifButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    [self.view addSubview:fakeNotifButton];
    

}

-(void)setupFakeNotifScreen:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; sender.alpha = 0.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

}

@end
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Use only the language tag that you are actually coding in.

Comment: kaylum my bad those were under the suggested tags so i figured it would be alright

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
UIView *blackOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

...that reference is inside the method `viewDidLoad`, so its existence is confined to that method. It is visible only inside the method, and indeed the reference goes out of existence when the method ends. (The view itself also goes out of existence; you have not put it into the interface.)

If you want a *persistent* reference to this view, you need to declare a *property* (or at least an instance variable, aka iva), and set it to this view. You still won't be able to do anything visible with the view if you don't actually put it into the interface.

Comment: See my  http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_instance_variables_and_accessors